# Axios ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

i have problem with node.js/Axios
When i trying to make call i've got error

xhr.js:220          GET http://localhost:5000/test net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

My node.js server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Reservations = require("./models/reservations");
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port);

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  console.log('test')

  res.send('test ')
})
```

My React components

```
Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/test").then(() => {
      console.log("test");
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: are you sure your server is running correctly

Comment: I am new to node.js. so i am not sure about it, but mongoose.connect() dont show any errors